# Keras fit_generator with images from directory and a constant tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a simple CNN with input images of shape (5,5,3). As a first step I want to add a constant tensor to the input.
According to the answer in my previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58107942/3195597), I have to define the constant tensor as an input layer (const_input), so that I can Add() it to the image data (raw_input). The model is compiled without errors:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Add
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# Python 2.7.10 - keras version 2.2.0 - tf.VERSION '1.8.0'

cnn_layer1 = Conv2D(32, (4, 4), activation='relu')
cnn_layer2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
cnn_layer3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')
cnn_layer4 = Dropout(0.1)
cnn_output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')

raw_input   = Input(shape=(5, 5, 3))
const_input = Input(shape=(5, 5, 3))

pre_proc = Add()([raw_input, const_input])
lay1 = cnn_layer1(pre_proc)
lay2 = cnn_layer2(lay1)
lay3 = Flatten()(lay2)
lay4 = cnn_layer3(lay3)
lay5 = cnn_layer4(lay4)
lay_out = cnn_output(lay5)

model = Model(inputs=[raw_input, const_input], outputs=lay_out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now I try to provide the constant tensor as an input along with the images that are read from directory:

```py
batch_size = 10
train_datagen      = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cd_data/train', 
        target_size=(5, 5), 
        classes=['cat', 'dog'],
        batch_size=batch_size) 

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cd_data/validation',
        target_size=(5, 5),
        classes=['cat', 'dog'],
        batch_size=batch_size)

const_array = np.array(
    [[[5.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,-3.0],[-10.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,4.0],[-20.0,0.0,0.0]],
    [[-15.0,0.0,12.0],[0.0,4.0,0.0],[-3.0,0.0,10.0],[-18.0,0.0,0.0],[20.0,0.0,-6.0]],
    [[0.0,0.0,6.0],[0.0,-2.0,-6.0],[0.0,0.0,2.0],[0.0,0.0,-9.0],[7.0,-6.0,0.0]],
    [[-3.0,4.0,0.0],[11.0,-12.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,7.0],[0.0,0.0,2.0]],
    [[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0,-2.0],[4.0,0.0,3.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]]])

def merge_generator():
        while True:
                next_image = train_generator.next() 
                yield [next_image[0], const_array], next_image[1]

train_gen_with_const = merge_generator()
```

Executing the fit_generator leads to error below

```py
model.fit_generator(
        train_gen_with_const,
        steps_per_epoch=2,
        epochs=1,
        verbose=2, # one line per epoch
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=2)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 5, 3)

I tried to provide the missing dimension like this

```py
const_batch = np.broadcast_to(const_array, (batch_size, 5, 5, 3))

def merge_generator():
        while True:
                next_image = train_generator.next() 
                yield [next_image[0], const_batch], next_image[1]
```

but this leads to

> ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(2, 5, 5, 3), (10, 5, 5, 3)]

What is the right way to provide this constant tensor input?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just for a sanity check, what is `const_batch.shape`?

Comment: const_batch.shape is (10, 5, 5, 3) There are 12 training images, so the 2 seems to be the remaining images from the second step in the epoch

Comment: If I make sure there are exactly 10 training and 10 validation images and call the fit_generator with 1 step, there is a ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[1. ... So there seems to be something fundamentally wrong with my approach

Comment: Are you sure you have data with expected format in the directory you're passing to `flow_from_directory`? What is the output of `print(next(train_generator))`? (P.S., to notify users of your replies, use @ - e.g. @OverLordGoldDragon)

Comment: And `print(next(merge_generator))` is also what you expect?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The output of `print(next(train_generator))` looks like expected: (array([[[[1., 0., 0.], ... {10 times the 5x5x3 image data} ]]]], dtype=float32), array([[0.,1.], ... {10 times the labels} [0., 1.]], dtype=float32))

Comment: @Jekapa What's the output of `X = next(train_generator); print(X[0].shape); print(X[1].shape)` (don't annotate anything)

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The `print(next(train_gen_with_const))` looks suspicious, in so far as the dtype=float32 is missing after the constants array:
(array([{10 times the 5x5x3 image data}], dtype=float32), array([{10 times the constants data}]), array([{10 times the labels}], dtype=float32))

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon (10, 5, 5, 3)
(10, 2)

Comment: @Jekapa I see where the problem is, but am noticing some inconsistencies between your comments' outputs and your question's error messages; run [this script](https://pastebin.com/T2N0eGNd), and paste its output to a new pastebin then share the link

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon https://pastebin.com/xk7ZsvJJ Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Before I post an answer, see if [this works](https://pastebin.com/BCbLzk8H)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200028/discussion-between-jekapa-and-overlordgolddragon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your `validation_data=` argument; your model expects *two* input arrays, whereas `validation_generator` supplies only *one*. You fixed this with `train_gen_with_const` - just extend it to val:

```py
def merge_generator(): # const_batch inside the function to apply to each image
    while True:
        next_image = train_generator.next()                      
        const_batch = np.broadcast_to(const_array, (len(next_image[0]), 5, 5, 3))
        yield [next_image[0], const_batch], next_image[1]

def val_merge_generator():  
    while True:
        next_image = validation_generator.next()
        const_batch = np.broadcast_to(const_array, (len(next_image[0]), 5, 5, 3))
        yield [next_image[0], const_batch], next_image[1]
```

Remember, internally, `fit_generator` calls `train_on_batch(x, y)` and `evaluate(x, y)` - so each must receive the same dimensionality for `x` and `y` from both generators.